# Cordova file plugin - overwrite files

Tags: file, cordova

As far as I can tell, there's no library call to replace a file (or folder). If I use `FileEntry.copyTo` or `DirectoryEntry.copyTo` and the destination exists, then I get `INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR` (error 9).

If I delete the file first, then `copyTo` works. But what if something goes wrong? Is there an overwrite option I've missed somewhere? Or do I have to write my own code to ensure that the copy is successful before removing the original?

Answer (score 3):

You can add the `exclusive: false` option parameter to overwrite existing files.

**Example** https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/README.md#create-a-persistent-file-

Comment: In this case though, I have to open the destination file? Which means I can't use `copyTo` and therefore there is no `overwrite` option for `copyTo`?

Comment: Does that also mean that the only way to overwrite a file is to write to the contents of the destination file via a stream?

Comment: Yes, copyTo does not provide this options parameter. Looks like the only way is to write everything in the destination file and delete the old file manually.

Comment: This works for overwriting one file but I cannot find something to overwrite a whole directory recursively. Do you know how to do that. (The obvious way of doing it manually is not an option for us due to performance reasons)